# How to make button disable without focus effect in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have 2 input fields and save button for an update operation. I need to make save button disabled if there is no change. My following code is working good, but the only problem is save button is becoming active if i click somewhere else on the screen (when input fields lose their onfocus, then save button is becoming active.)

Template code is:

```
<mat-card-content>
        <h1 class="new-header">Enter New Values</h1>
        <div fxLayout="row">
          <mat-form-field fxFlex="20">
            <input matInput name="label" [(ngModel)]="employee.label" placeholder="Label"
                   (change)="onInputFieldChange()"
                   required>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div fxLayout="row">
          <mat-form-field fxFlex="50">
            <input matInput name="postalAddress"
                   [(ngModel)]="employee.postalAddress" placeholder="Postal Address"
                   (change)="onInputFieldChange()" required>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
</mat-card-content>

<button type="button" id="update" class="button-style" (click)="onSaveEmployee()"
                [disabled]="!filterDataSelected || !employee.label" > Save
</button>
```

and ts method is:

```
public onInputFieldChange() {
    this.filterDataSelected = true;
}
```

As I said disable/enable button part is working good but it is working only input fields lose onfocus. So how can i make the button enabled/disabled dynamically ?

Comment: It sounds like the values in `employee` are predefined. The most elegant way is to use a `FormGroup` and disable the button when the form is `pristine || invalid`.

Comment: I don't understand what's the exact issue?
It's working as expected. see I've reproduced your code in this example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jbbut4?file=app%2Fbutton-types-example.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not that familiar with angular, but I think the problem comes from the nature of the `change` event. This js event is triggered for input fields as soon as they loose focus. the fact if the actual text inside has changed doesn't matter. So everytime your input looses focus you set `filterDataSelected` to true and therefore your button gets visible.

> The change event triggers when the element has finished changing. For
>   text inputs that means that **the event occurs when it loses focus**. For
>   instance, **while we are typing in the text field** below – **there’s no
>   event**. But when we move the focus somewhere else, for instance, click
>   on a button – there will be a change event

Source: https://javascript.info/events-change-input

I would solve this by either:

- Checking for changes inside the `onInputFieldChange` callback. But you would need to save the initial value of the field somehow so you can compare it.
- Using a different event trigger. Instead of `onchange` you could use the `onkeyup` event, which gets triggered right after you pressed a key. Because I think its valid to assume something changed if the user pressed a key inside your input field.